# Unnecessary Startup Command in Azure Pipelines for .NET Core Project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I've created a Linux App Service running .NET Core 2.2 on Azure. When I go to the deployment center and choose Azure-Repos/ Azure-Pipelines as the source control and then select my MVC Core repo, i'm required to enter a Startup Command, but deleting the command afterwards in the App Service's Configuration - General-Settings doesn't actually prevent the website from running?

**Edit:**
Actually, if I don't delete the Start-up command after deployment my app wouldn't run!

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, AFAIK, it is true that the Startup command should be optional in the Deployment Center configuration blade, like it is in the [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#prerequisites-for-the-task), unless it's needed for some other specific reason.

I shall check with our internal teams about this and get back with more details as I have them. Thanks for the question!

---

**Update:**
@jcmontx We have created a workitem to track and fix this. Please note that there are some other high priority changes planned for Linux Web App continuous delivery which will have effect on how startup command is handled. This means we will have first wait for these to complete before processing the requested change. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @jcmontx We have created a workitem to track and fix this. Please note that there are some other high priority changes planned for Linux Web App continuous delivery which will have effect on how startup command is handled. This means we will have first wait for these to complete before processing the requested change. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Any updates on this, or a link to the work item so we can track? Every time there is a deployment triggered by the pipeline, the deployed website breaks. I have to log in and go to **App Service => Configuration => General Settings** and manually remove the **Startup Command** that was required during CI setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The only solution I found to this was to:

1. Add a random comment as Startup Command (your build may fail the first time) when setting up the Pipeline in the Deployment Center.
2. Then go to Azure Pipelines -> Releases -> Select YourPipeline -> Edit -> Tasks -> Select "Deploy Azure App Service"
3. Scroll down the options and you'll find "Startup command"
4. Remove your previous input (step 1)
5. Save

Comment: problem is that this is exactly what does NOT work. When you check the kudu deployment logs... the application starting with the "deleted" startup command. It looks like startup command is removed from DevOps only, not from the actual deployment.